# Tons of Errors building Gazebo on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I try to build gazebo, and I have been trying for 2 hours now. I receive many errors. I have installed every boost library i can think of, ogre, sdf, etc, etc etc. And it still will not compile. It still tells me I need boost. Boost is already installed. The output of cmake reads:

```
:~/Code/gazebo_maps/build$ cmake ../
-- Gazebo version 2.0.0
-- Found CPack generators: DEB
-- High memory tests: enabled
-- 

====== Finding 3rd Party Packages ======
-- Operating system is Linux
-- checking for module 'freeimage>='
Must specify package names on the command line
--   package 'freeimage>=' not found
--   freeimage.pc not found, trying freeimage_include_dir and freeimage_library_dir flags.
--   Looking for FreeImage.h - found
--   Looking for libfreeimage - found
-- checking for module 'libprofiler'
--   package 'libprofiler' not found
-- Looking for libprofiler - not found
-- checking for module 'libtcmalloc'
--   package 'libtcmalloc' not found
-- Looking for libtcmalloc - not found
-- Looking for CEGUI, found
-- Looking for CEGUI-OGRE, found
CMake Warning at cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake:130 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSimbody.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Simbody", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Simbody" with any
  of the following names:

    SimbodyConfig.cmake
    simbody-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Simbody" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Simbody_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Simbody" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:149 (include)


--  Simbody not found, for simbody physics engine option, please install libsimbody-dev.
-- Looking for tinyxml.h - found
-- Looking for libtar.h - found
Package OGRE was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `OGRE.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'OGRE' found
CMake Error at cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake:187 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:149 (include)


-- checking for module 'OGRE-Overlay'
--   package 'OGRE-Overlay' not found
--  Failed to find OGRE's plugin directory.  The build will succeed, but gazebo will likely fail to run.
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   package 'libswscale' not found
--  libswscale not found. Audio-video capabilities will be disabled.
-- checking for module 'libavformat'
--   package 'libavformat' not found
--  libavformat not found. Audio-video capabilities will be disabled.
-- checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   package 'libavcodec' not found
--  libavcodec not found. Audio-video capabilities will be disabled.
-- checking for modules 'playercore>=3.0;playerc++'
--   package 'playercore>=3.0' not found
--   package 'playerc++' not found
--  Player not found, gazebo plugin for player will not be built.
-- checking for module 'gts'
--   package 'gts' not found
--  GNU Triangulation Surface library not found - Gazebo will not have CSG support.
-- Boost version: 1.53.0
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1126 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.53.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

      boost_signals
      boost_system
      boost_filesystem
      boost_program_options
      boost_regex
      boost_iostreams

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake:337 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:149 (include)


--  Boost not found. Please install thread signals system filesystem program_options regex date_time boost version 1.40.0 or higher.
-- Looking for ltdl.h - found
-- Looking for libltdl - found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for libdl - found
--  ronn not found, manpages won't be generated
-- ----------------------------------------

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:164 (string):
  string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.


-- Looking for display capabilities
--  + found a display available ($DISPLAY is set)
--  ! valid dri display not found (no glxinfo or pyopengl)
-- Checking gazebo build type
-- Enable host CFlags
-- 
SSE4 disabled.

-- Enable upstream CFlags
-- 

====== Configuring 3rd Party Packages ======
-- ----------------------------------------

-- BUILD WARNINGS
--  Simbody not found, for simbody physics engine option, please install libsimbody-dev.
--  Failed to find OGRE's plugin directory.  The build will succeed, but gazebo will likely fail to run.
--  libswscale not found. Audio-video capabilities will be disabled.
--  libavformat not found. Audio-video capabilities will be disabled.
--  libavcodec not found. Audio-video capabilities will be disabled.
--  Player not found, gazebo plugin for player will not be built.
--  GNU Triangulation Surface library not found - Gazebo will not have CSG support.
--  ronn not found, manpages won't be generated
-- END BUILD WARNINGS

-- BUILD ERRORS: These must be resolved before compiling.
--  Boost not found. Please install thread signals system filesystem program_options regex date_time boost version 1.40.0 or higher.
-- END BUILD ERRORS

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:265 (message):
  Errors encountered in build.  Please see the BUILD ERRORS above.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
dev@dev-700Z7C:~/Code/gazebo_maps/build$
```

**Environment variables**

```
dev@dev-700Z7C:~$ env
XDG_VTNR=7
SSH_AGENT_PID=2220
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
SESSION=ubuntu
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/keyring-ck7G7c/gpg:0:1
TERM=xterm
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
SHELL=/bin/bash
VTE_VERSION=3406
WINDOWID=65011719
UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/2149
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/1000/keyring-ck7G7c
GTK_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module
USER=dev
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring-ck7G7c/ssh
SESSION_MANAGER=local/dev-700Z7C:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2278,unix/dev-700Z7C:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2278
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg
PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
JOB=dbus
PWD=/home/dev
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=2147
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
GDM_LANG=en_US
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session
SHLVL=1
XDG_SEAT=seat0
HOME=/home/dev
LANGUAGE=en_US
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
UPSTART_EVENTS=started xsession
LOGNAME=dev
COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/
QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-jOy5TOgYnb
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
INSTANCE=
UPSTART_JOB=gnome-session
TEXTDOMAIN=im-config
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
XAUTHORITY=/home/dev/.Xauthority
_=/usr/bin/env
dev@dev-700Z7C:~$
```

I tried to install from source for the Gazebo 2.0 vesion. The following is the output from dpkg as well as from the install dependencies portion of the source installation guide:

```
    dev@dev-700Z7C:~$ dpkg -l | grep libogre 
    ii  libogre-1.7.4:amd64                       1.7.4+dfsg1-7                           amd64        3D Object-Oriented Graphics Rendering Engine (libraries)
    ii  libogre-1.8.0:amd64                       1.8.1+dfsg-0ubuntu1                     amd64        3D Object-Oriented Graphics Rendering Engine (libraries)
    
    dev@dev-700Z7C:~$ dpkg -l | grep libboost
    ii  libboost-all-dev                          1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        Boost C++ Libraries development files (ALL) (default version)
    ii  libboost-atomic-dev:amd64                 1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        atomic data types, operations, and memory ordering constraints (default version)
    ii  libboost-atomic1.53-dev:amd64             1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        atomic data types, operations, and memory ordering constraints
    ii  libboost-atomic1.53.0:amd64               1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        atomic data types, operations, and memory ordering constraints
    ii  libboost-chrono-dev:amd64                 1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks (default version)
    ii  libboost-chrono1.53-dev:amd64             1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks
    ii  libboost-chrono1.53.0:amd64               1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C++ representation of time duration, time point, and clocks
    ii  libboost-context-dev:amd64                1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        provides a sort of cooperative multitasking on a single thread (default version)
    ii  libboost-context1.53-dev:amd64            1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        provides a sort of cooperative multitasking on a single thread
    ii  libboost-context1.53.0:amd64              1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        provides a sort of cooperative multitasking on a single thread
    ii  libboost-date-time-dev:amd64              1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts (default version)
    ii  libboost-date-time1.49.0                  1.49.0-4                                amd64        set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts
    ii  libboost-date-time1.53-dev:amd64          1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts
    ii  libboost-date-time1.53.0:amd64            1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts
    ii  libboost-dev:amd64                        1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        Boost C++ Libraries development files (default version)
    ii  libboost-exception-dev:amd64              1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts (default version)
    ii  libboost-exception1.53-dev:amd64          1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        set of date-time libraries based on generic programming concepts
    ii  libboost-filesystem-dev:amd64             1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        filesystem operations (portable paths, iteration over directories, etc) in C++ (default version)
    ii  libboost-filesystem1.53-dev:amd64         1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        filesystem operations (portable paths, iteration over directories, etc) in C++
    ii  libboost-filesystem1.53.0:amd64           1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        filesystem operations (portable paths, iteration over directories, etc) in C++
    ii  libboost-graph-dev:amd64                  1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        generic graph components and algorithms in C++ (default version)
    ii  libboost-graph-parallel-dev               1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        generic graph components and algorithms in C++ (default version)
    ii  libboost-graph-parallel1.53-dev           1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        generic graph components and algorithms in C++
    ii  libboost-graph-parallel1.53.0             1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        generic graph components and algorithms in C++
    ii  libboost-graph1.53-dev:amd64              1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        generic graph components and algorithms in C++
    ii  libboost-graph1.53.0:amd64                1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        generic graph components and algorithms in C++
    ii  libboost-iostreams-dev                    1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        Boost.Iostreams Library development files (default version)
    ii  libboost-iostreams1.53-dev:amd64          1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Boost.Iostreams Library development files
    ii  libboost-iostreams1.53.0:amd64            1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Boost.Iostreams Library
    ii  libboost-locale-dev:amd64                 1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        C++ facilities for localization (default version)
    ii  libboost-locale1.53-dev:amd64             1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C++ facilities for localization
    ii  libboost-locale1.53.0:amd64               1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C++ facilities for localization
    ii  libboost-math-dev:amd64                   1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        Boost.Math Library development files (default version)
    ii  libboost-math1.53-dev:amd64               1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Boost.Math Library development files
    ii  libboost-math1.53.0:amd64                 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Boost.Math Library
    ii  libboost-mpi-dev                          1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI) (default version)
    ii  libboost-mpi-python-dev                   1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI), Python Bindings (default version)
    ii  libboost-mpi-python1.53-dev               1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI), Python Bindings
    ii  libboost-mpi-python1.53.0                 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI), Python Bindings
    ii  libboost-mpi1.53-dev                      1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI)
    ii  libboost-mpi1.53.0                        1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C++ interface to the Message Passing Interface (MPI)
    ii  libboost-program-options-dev:amd64        1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        program options library for C++ (default version)
    ii  libboost-program-options1.53-dev:amd64    1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        program options library for C++
    ii  libboost-program-options1.53.0:amd64      1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        program options library for C++
    ii  libboost-python-dev                       1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        Boost.Python Library development files (default version)
    ii  libboost-python1.53-dev                   1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Boost.Python Library development files
    ii  libboost-python1.53.0                     1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Boost.Python Library
    ii  libboost-random-dev:amd64                 1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        Boost Random Number Library (default version)
    ii  libboost-random1.53-dev:amd64             1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Boost Random Number Library
    ii  libboost-random1.53.0:amd64               1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Boost Random Number Library
    ii  libboost-regex-dev                        1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        regular expression library for C++ (default version)
    ii  libboost-regex1.53-dev:amd64              1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        regular expression library for C++
    ii  libboost-regex1.53.0:amd64                1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        regular expression library for C++
    ii  libboost-serialization-dev:amd64          1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        serialization library for C++ (default version)
    ii  libboost-serialization1.49.0              1.49.0-4                                amd64        serialization library for C++
    ii  libboost-serialization1.53-dev:amd64      1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        serialization library for C++
    ii  libboost-serialization1.53.0:amd64        1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        serialization library for C++
    ii  libboost-signals-dev:amd64                1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        managed signals and slots library for C++ (default version)
    ii  libboost-signals1.53-dev:amd64            1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        managed signals and slots library for C++
    ii  libboost-signals1.53.0:amd64              1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        managed signals and slots library for C++
    ii  libboost-system-dev:amd64                 1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        Operating system (e.g. diagnostics support) library (default version)
    ii  libboost-system1.53-dev:amd64             1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Operating system (e.g. diagnostics support) library
    ii  libboost-system1.53.0:amd64               1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Operating system (e.g. diagnostics support) library
    ii  libboost-test-dev:amd64                   1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        components for writing and executing test suites (default version)
    ii  libboost-test1.53-dev:amd64               1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        components for writing and executing test suites
    ii  libboost-test1.53.0:amd64                 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        components for writing and executing test suites
    ii  libboost-thread-dev:amd64                 1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        portable C++ multi-threading (default version)
    ii  libboost-thread1.49.0                     1.49.0-4                                amd64        portable C++ multi-threading
    ii  libboost-thread1.53-dev:amd64             1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        portable C++ multi-threading
    ii  libboost-thread1.53.0:amd64               1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        portable C++ multi-threading
    ii  libboost-timer-dev:amd64                  1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        C++ wall clock and CPU process timers (default version)
    ii  libboost-timer1.53-dev:amd64              1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C++ wall clock and CPU process timers
    ii  libboost-timer1.53.0:amd64                1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C++ wall clock and CPU process timers
    ii  libboost-tools-dev                        1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        Boost C++ Libraries development tools (default version)
    ii  libboost-wave-dev:amd64                   1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        C99/C++ preprocessor library (default version)
    ii  libboost-wave1.53-dev:amd64               1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C99/C++ preprocessor library
    ii  libboost-wave1.53.0:amd64                 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        C99/C++ preprocessor library
    ii  libboost1.53-dev:amd64                    1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Boost C++ Libraries development files
    ii  libboost1.53-tools-dev                    1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8                    amd64        Boost C++ Libraries development tools

dev@dev-700Z7C:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libtinyxml-dev libboost-all-dev cmake mercurial pkg-config \
>              libprotoc-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libqt4-dev libtar-dev \
>              libcurl4-openssl-dev libcegui-mk2-dev libopenal-dev libsimbody-dev libtbb-dev \
>              libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libogre-1.8-dev libgts-dev libltdl3-dev \
>              playerc++ libxml2-dev libfreeimage-dev freeglut3-dev
[sudo] password for dev: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libltdl-dev' instead of 'libltdl3-dev'
Note, selecting 'libplayercommon-dev' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc3.0-dev' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc2-dev' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc++3.0-dev' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc3.0' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc++-dev' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'ruby-playerc' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayercommon3.0' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'python2.7-playerc' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc-dev' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayercore2-dev' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc++3.0' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc++2-dev' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayercore3.0-dev' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayercommon3.0-dev' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayercore-dev' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'python-playerc' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayercore3.0' for regex 'playerc+'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc++3.0-dev' instead of 'libplayerc++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc++3.0-dev' instead of 'libplayerc++2-dev'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc3.0-dev' instead of 'libplayerc-dev'
Note, selecting 'libplayerc3.0-dev' instead of 'libplayerc2-dev'
Note, selecting 'libplayercommon3.0-dev' instead of 'libplayercommon-dev'
Note, selecting 'libplayercore3.0-dev' instead of 'libplayercore-dev'
Note, selecting 'libplayercore3.0-dev' instead of 'libplayercore2-dev'
Note, selecting 'python-playerc' instead of 'python2.7-playerc'
E: Unable to locate package libsimbody-dev

dev@dev-700Z7C:~$ sudo apt-get install libbullet-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libbullet-dev is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-date-time1.49.0 libboost-serialization1.49.0 libogre-1.7.4 libxaw7-dev libxpm-dev libzzip-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4915/tons-of-errors-building-gazebo-on-ubuntu-13.10/) by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 48 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-11-05**:
It also can't find ogre. Can you paste the output of the following commands to see which debs you have installed? `dpkg -l | grep libogre` and `dpkg -l | grep libboost`

**Comment by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on 2013-11-05**:
dev@dev-700Z7C:~$ dpkg -l | grep libogre 
ii  libogre-1.7.4:amd64                       1.7.4+dfsg1-7                           amd64        3D Object-Oriented Graphics Rendering Engine (libraries)
ii  libogre-1.8.0:amd64                       1.8.1+dfsg-0ubuntu1                     amd64        3D Object-Oriented Graphics Rendering Engine (libraries)
dev@dev-700Z7C:~$ dpkg -l | grep libboost
ii  libboost-all-dev                          1.53.0.0ubuntu2                         amd64        Boost

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-11-05**:
Well they are definitely installed. How about your environment variables? Output of `env`

**Comment by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on 2013-11-05**:
Below is the environment variables. I am not sure what to be looking for in them though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

By any chance, did you follow the [from source installation guide](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/2.0/install#Compiling_From_Source_.28Ubuntu.29)?

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on 2013-11-05**:
Yes I did, the output of it at the bottom of the other answer I just posted.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-11-06**:
Thanks for the information. All looks ok to me. Could you please try to remove the build/ directory completely, create it again and run cmake ..?

**Comment by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on 2013-11-06**:
I deleted the entire directory after performing a custom build of simbody, and performing the install command nkoenig gave. When I did that, and redownloaded the code, cmake completed without errors. I am in the process of building it now.

**Comment by [aqiruse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/110/aqiruse/) on 2013-11-07**:
I was able to compile the code, however I had some trouble running it after the install. The path would be /usr/local/lib for the libgazebo* librarys i thought but instead it is /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ on my system. Once I figured that out using find -name "libgazebo*" and corrected the bashrc I am able to launch gazebo now. Next comes ROS hookup.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-11-07**:
Perfect, good luck. Could you mark this thread as solved clicking on the check button?